# How to use jq to extract a particular field from a terraform state file?

Tags: json, select, terraform, jq

Here is a simplified json file of a terraform state file (let's call it dev.ftstate)

```
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "0.12.9",
  "serial": 2,
  "lineage": "ba56cc3e-71fd-1488-e6fb-3136f4630e70",
  "outputs": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "module": "module.rds.module.reports_cpu_warning",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "datadog_monitor",
      "name": "alert",
      "each": "list",
      "provider": "module.rds.provider.datadog",
      "instances": []
    },
    {
      "module": "module.rds.module.reports_lag_warning",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "datadog_monitor",
      "name": "alert",
      "each": "list",
      "provider": "module.rds.provider.datadog",
      "instances": []
    },
    {
      "module": "module.rds.module.cross_region_replica_lag_alert",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "datadog_monitor",
      "name": "alert",
      "each": "list",
      "provider": "module.rds.provider.datadog",
      "instances": []
    },
    {
      "module": "module.rds",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "aws_db_instance",
      "name": "master",
      "provider": "provider.aws",
      "instances": [
        {
          "schema_version": 0,
          "attributes": {
            "address": "dev-database.123456.us-east-8.rds.amazonaws.com",
            "allocated_storage": 10,            
            "password": "",
            "performance_insights_enabled": false,
            "tags": {
              "env": "development"
            },
            "timeouts": {
              "create": "6h",
              "delete": "6h",
              "update": "6h"
            },
            "timezone": "",
            "username": "admin",
            "vpc_security_group_ids": [
              "sg-1234"
            ]
          },
          "private": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There are many modules at the same level of `module.rds` inside the `instances`. I took out many of them to create the simplified version of the raw data. The key takeway: do not assume the array index will be constant in all cases.

I wanted to extract the `password` field in the above example.

My first attempt is to use equality check to extract the relevant modules

```
` jq '.resources[].module == "module.rds"' dev.tfstate`
```

but it actually just produced a list of boolean values. I don't see any mention of builtin functions like  `filter` in `jq`'s manual

then I tried to just access the field:

```
> jq '.resources[].module[].attributes[].password?' dev.tfstate
```

then it throws the following error

```
jq: error (at dev.tfstate:1116): Cannot iterate over string ("module.rds")
```

So what is the best way to extract the value? Hopefully it can only focus on the `password` attribute in `module.rds` module only.

Edit:

My purpose is to detect if a password is left inside a state file. I want to ensure the passwords are exclusively stored in AWS secret manager.

Comment: How do you get around the fact that the password is a required argument for creating an rds resource? https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html#password What does it mean "left inside a state file"? Do you edit the state file to wipe the value or something? If you do that then running `terraform apply` will detect a difference an could potentially reset the password to that blank. I'm curious about best practice and your security approach here, I thought rotating password, using encrypted tf backend or terraform cloud/ consul should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the module you want like this.

```
jq '.resources[] | select(.module == "module.rds")'
```

I'm not confident that I understand the requirements for the rest of the solution. So this might not only not be the *best* way of doing what you want; it might not do what you want at all!

If you know where password will be, you can do this.

```
jq '.resources[] | select(.module == "module.rds") | .instances[].attributes.password'
```

If you don't know exactly where password will be, this is a way of finding it.

```
jq '.resources[] | select(.module == "module.rds") | .. | .password? | values'
```

According to the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/) under the heading "Recursive Descent," `..|.a?` will "find all the values of object keys “a” in any object found “below” ."

`values` filters out the null results.

Answer (score 2):

You could also get the password value out of the state file without `jq` by using Terraform [outputs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html). Your module should define an output with the value you want to output and you should also output this at the root module.

Without seeing your Terraform code you'd want something like this:

#### modules/rds/main.tf

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "master" {
  # ...
}

output "password" {
  value = aws_db_instance.master.password

  sensitive = true
}
```

#### example/main.tf

```
module "rds" {
  source = "../modules/rds"
  # ...
}

output "rds_password" {
  value = module.rds.password

  sensitive = true
}
```

The `sensitive = true` parameter means that Terraform won't print the output to stdout when running `terraform apply` but it's still held in plain text in the state file.

To then access this value without `jq` you can use the [`terraform output` command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/output.html) which will retrieve the output from the state file and print it to stdout. From there you can use it however you want.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made my intention clearer in my question: I want to ensure no password is left in the state files.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the password is going to be in the state file anyway unless you change the password out of band and have something other than Terraform put the database password into SSM. Is there a reason you can't have the password in the state file? I restrict access to the KMS key used to encrypt/decrypt state files and that gives me enough access control over secrets in state files.